# Use `Max()` with `GROUP BY` in MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, sql

In `MySQL 5.7`, I have the following `orders` and `transactions` tables respectively. And I want to get the maximum `transaction.timestamp` for each product where `orders.status` is "done".

[image]

I used the following query:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(timestamp), 
    product, 
    idorder, 
    idtransaction,
    order_name 
FROM 
    transaction left join orders 
ON 
    transaction.order_id=orders.idorder 
WHERE
    status='done' 
GROUP BY
    'product';
```

But it resulted in an error as follows:

> Error Code: 1055. Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY
>   clause and contains nonaggregated column
>   'openbank_consentdb.transaction.product' which is not functionally
>   dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with
>   sql_mode=only_full_group_by

I understand the problem here, sql is unable to understand how to `GROUP BY` because there are multiple categories. How to write it so that it returns the details relevant to records with the maximum timestamp for each product?

Comment: Why are you using `sql_mode=only_full_group_by` ? If you dont have to, you can change it and your query works as it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want:

```
SELECT t.product, MAX(timestamp)
FROM transaction t join
     orders o
    ON t.order_id = o.idorder 
WHERE o.status = 'done' 
GROUP BY t.product;
```

Notes:

- Presumably, all transactions are in a valid order, so you don't need an outer join.
- Qualify all column names, so the query is unambiguous.
- Do not put single quotes around column names.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.
- This does not include the ids for transactions and orders.  Such ids don't make sense for a query returning information about products.

EDIT:

It occurs to me that you want to full transaction information for the most recent transaction for each product that is "done".  If so, I would go for a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM transaction t 
WHERE t.timestamp = (SELECT MAX(t2.timestamp)
                     FROM transaction t2 JOIN
                          orders o2
                          ON t2.order_id = o2.idorder 
                     WHERE o2.status = 'done' AND t2.product = t.product
                    );
```

Comment: Yes but with other column values too. The problem I asked is like the simplified version of a bigger problem (so I need the other values too)

Comment: @SachiDangalla . . . It occurred to me what you really want to do.  Your question doesn't fully explain it.

Comment: @SachiDangalla check my new answer to see another way of doing this. You can use the query in your question with a little trick actually.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks. Is it possible to get `orders` column values too?

Answer (score 1):

```
 select * from ( SELECT 
        MAX(timestamp)timestamp, 
        product
    FROM 
        transaction left join orders 
    ON 
        transaction.order_id=orders.idorder 
    WHERE
        status='done' 
    GROUP BY
        product ) a
   join 

  (SELECT 
        *
    FROM 
        transaction left join orders 
    ON 
        transaction.order_id=orders.idorder 
    WHERE
        status='done' 
 )b on a.timestamp=b.timestamp and a.product=b.product
```

Comment: The error is gone, yes, but this gives all the results where `status=done`. I want one result for each product, where the timestamp is thelatest one.

Comment: Over will not work because window functions are implemented in mysql 8.0, not in 5.7

Comment: Hmm ok back to the original then

Comment: It actually works, I was trying to see if it can be simplified a bit.

Comment: It could be if we could use window functions

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same query with a simple trick. With the default sql mode in mysql 5.7, you can use ANY_VALUE to bypass that error.

```
SELECT 
  MAX(timestamp), 
  product, 
  ANY_VALUE(idorder),
  ANY_VALUE(idtransaction) 
FROM 
  transaction left join orders 
ON 
  transaction.order_id=orders.idorder 
WHERE
  status='done' 
GROUP BY
  'product';
```

Check the docs to understand in detail why ANY_VALUE is neccesary here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value.

Comment: This does not return the correct (relevant) values.

Comment: The `idorder` and `idtransaction` are not the correct ones (because of ANY_VALUE I guess)

Comment: Hmm okay, i double checked docs and saw that ANY_VALUE makes the column nondeterministic so that i may not give you the correct values for the aggregated row